# Subdivision modifier cutting through corners on hard-corners

Tags: modeling

I've been trying to smooth out edges on my model for hours with no luck, using Auto-Smooth and Shade Smooth, and even adding the Subdivision modifier. What I didn't do before was add and EdgeSplit modifier before the Subdivision modifier. Finally, everything looks good except these top two sharp edges...
*Before, with hard, rounded edges*
[image: Before, with hard, rounded edges]

*After, with good rounded edges, except for those top two*
[image: After, with good rounded edges, except for those top two]

*Modifier settings*
[image: Modifier settings]

Comment: Can you please provide your blend file so we can help you?

Comment: Looks like your faces are not connected, you could try to select the vertices in edit mode and Merge by distance (M on the keyboard)

Comment: Please do not upload a blend file, the problem is the edge split. Use edge creases in edit mode instead (shortcut: **Shift E**).

Comment: @HISEROD: why don't you answer instead of answering in the comments?

Comment: It's one of those answers that is so niche and simple that it is hardly worth the effort of properly formatting and screenshotting etc. If you want to snag some rep, feel free to steal my answer 

Comment: @HISEROD: thank you for this kind offer, but i only want to write an answer which i found out by myself or know now. ;) and my main goal here is not getting scores but helping people because i got lot's of help here too by great people with amazing knowledge. And i don't think an answer must be "perfect". If the OP understood - and he did - other people will do too - i think ;) so - just my opinion - i would have copied your 1,5 sentences to the answer ;)

Comment: Thank you all; that worked quite well :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the *Edge Split* modifier. You can use *Edge Crease* in edit mode instead by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

[image: 1]

Comment: That fixed it; thank you so much!!